# Pagination scroll top in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm currently create chat in flutter and get the last messages , I want to handle when scrolling to top to load more messages how can I create that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement [swipe to refresh](https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-swipe-to-refresh.html#usage) kind of behaviour, you can use [RefreshIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html). See the example and usage in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORApMlzwMdM).

All you have to do is wrap your scrollable widget (it can be `ListView` or `SingleChildScrollView`) in a `RefreshIndicator` and provide `onRefresh` method:

```
class PullToRefresh extends StatelessWidget {
  const PullToRefresh({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: _refreshData,
      child: ListView.builder( // or SingleChildScrollView
        ...
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _refreshData() async {
    // load more items
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ListView `reverse: true` displays the List from the bottom to the top.

and this is how to implement pagination

```
class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  ScrollController? controller;
  final _all = <WordPair>[];
  final _saved = Set<WordPair>();
  final _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _all.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(20));
    controller = ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    controller?.dispose();
  }

  void _scrollListener() {
    if (controller!.position.pixels == controller!.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      startLoader();
    }
  }

  void startLoader() {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = !isLoading;
      fetchData();
    });
  }

  fetchData() async {
    var _duration = const Duration(seconds: 2);
    return Timer(_duration, onResponse);
  }

  void onResponse() {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = !isLoading;
      _all.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(20));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          "List load more example",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildSuggestions(),
          _loader(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRow(WordPair pair) {
    final alreadySaved = _saved.contains(pair);
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          title: Text(
            pair.asPascalCase,
            style: _biggerFont,
          ),
          trailing: Icon(
            alreadySaved ? Icons.check : Icons.check,
            color: alreadySaved ? Colors.deepOrange : null,
          ),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              if (alreadySaved) {
                _saved.remove(pair);
              } else {
                _saved.add(pair);
              }
            });
          },
        ),
        const Divider(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSuggestions() {
    return ListView.builder(
        reverse: true,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        controller: controller,
        itemCount: _all.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return _buildRow(_all[i]);
        });
  }

  Widget _loader() {
    return isLoading
        ? const Align(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 70.0,
              height: 70.0,
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
            ),
            alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
          )
        : const SizedBox(
            width: 0.0,
            height: 0.0,
          );
  }
}
```

You can get full code from [Github HERE](https://github.com/FadyFouad/pagination_chat)